# Laravel Command->choice looping

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Using Laravel 5.2 (currently the latest release) is looping when using the artisan function choice(). My code is basic:

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;

class TestCommand extends Command
{
    protected $signature = 'function:menu';

    public function handle() {
        $this->choice('select yes', ['yes']);
    }
}
```

When I run

```
php artisan function:menu
```

I get

```
select yes:
  [0] yes
 >


 [ERROR] Undefined variable: output

select yes:
  [0] yes
 >


 [ERROR] Undefined variable: output
```

It loops through that non-stop without waiting for input. It works fine on Windows 7 and Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie), but a fresh install of laravel on CentOS release 6.7 (Final) does this. Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a custom php.ini, I removed `shell_exec` and `exec` from the `disable_functions` setting. This fixed it. I previously did not know it had been disabled in the default php.ini.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the error is not the result of the choice handle you made. Check your logs for more information as I think the source is somewhere else in your app.

```
cat -n 100 storage/logs/__your_latest_logfile.log
```